# Postgres find numbers start with

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a big int `mobile_number` column in my `users` table, I want to find users for a specific operator

My current query is so slow and I have no idea how can I add an index to make it faster, I am looking for an index or alternative faster solution

```sql
SELECT mobile_number 
FROM users 
WHERE mobile_number::TEXT~'^98(?:901|902|903|904|905|930|933|935|936|937|938|939)'
```

How can I make a `start with` regex faster? I tried `gin_trgm_ops` but not works

Please ignore the following solutions:

1. Adding a pre calculated `operator` column
2. Comparing numbers `mobile_number>= 989010000000 AND mobile_number<= 989019999999`

Comment: " I tried gin_trgm_ops but not works"  What does that mean?  You couldn't build it?  It was not chosen for use by the planner? It was used, but not actually fast?

Comment: I mean, it has no affect on query plan and actual time of query running, the index is not choosed by postgres because it's not appropriate index

Comment: gin_trgm_ops works for me.  Does it get used if you set enable_seqscan=off?   What version of PostgreSQL and pg_trgm are you using?

Comment: Are you sure? I tested today with postgres 13 and enable_seqscan=off

Comment: Can you send me the command that create index?

Comment: `create index ON  users using gin ((mobile_number::text) gin_trgm_ops);`

Comment: I do exactly same! I will try tomorrow may be it's my fault